# Would this fill the child context with only TemporaryIDs?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, concurrency

I was wondering if someone would be able to answer this question. I am currently building my application using the CoreData stack as described by Marcus Zarra in his blog http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/03/core-data-stack/. He describes the usage of managedObjectContext as the *Single Source Of Truth* where all insertions/updates/deletions should be done on this context. No exceptions. Curiously then, since this context is a child context to the private context, if I keep inserting new NSManagedObjects into managedObjectContext... wouldn't this context be filled with temporaryObjectIDs since the parent does not refresh the child context? I ask this question because how would I retrieve this NSManagedObject back from the PSC using the NSManagedObjectID if I only have the temporary one? Would I have to explicitly throw out another performBlock using the privateContext to fetch for it? That feels like a very inelegant of a solution.

Comment: Updated my answer with suggestion to not design unnecessary complexity into app. Don't pass IDs if you don't need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the conversion to happen early, before you've saved changes, like so:

```
[moc obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:moc.insertedObjects.allObjects error:&error];
```

As I understand it, the object is already in both contexts.  You don't need to retrieve it from the store, as it's cached.

You still have the object and could query the store, based on the object's attributes.  The only need for the ID was if you needed to pass it to another thread, but you only have the one Single Source Of Truth.  What other thread is there?

**Update:**

After discussing your app, I would suggest not to add complexity if there is no need for complexity.  You already have an API thread.  Don't try to prematurely optimize it by splitting an API task into multithreaded sub tasks.  You're adding overhead and the unnecessary burden of passing IDs between private contexts.

Treat what the background API is doing as a single operation, and let it download, insert, save, then notify the SSoT, which can then (re)fetch.

If it is responsive enough, you're done.  You have a simple, contained approach, with no need to pass IDs.

In general, don't optimize unless there's a need for it.

Comment: I am aware of this solution, but I've been getting weird behaviours from this. I often times encounter EXC_BAD_ACCESS exceptions despite ensuring the NSManagedObject has a temporary objectID. But beyond that, I think if you have to forcefully query the objectID from the PSC like that.. it feels like that isn't how Apple originally imagined it to be done?

EDIT: I have experimented with doing this before and after the save call.

Comment: Curiously then, is it not better practice to always pass around NSManagedObjectIDs between functions that require the NSManagedObject? It makes it more portable and thread-safe, albeit at the cost of some inconvenience. Right now, I only have one main thread accessing CoreData. I am also using existingObjectWithId to instantiate the NSManagedObject in the event I need to use the data within.

Comment: Is your app threaded?  If not, just pass the `NSManagedObject`.  The only time you need the object ID when your app isn't threaded, is for state restoration.

Comment: My app is threaded. I would like to keep all the long operations/server API calls be done on a separate thread. Currently that is being done with GCD dispatch calls.

Comment: Yes, you'd need to obtain the permanent ID before passing it to another thread, as you can't pass `NSManagedObjects` between threads.

Comment: So am I just approaching this whole concurrency idea wrong, or is obtainPermanentIDs my only solution?

Comment: To avoid any confusion, let's make sure we're talking about the same things.  There are two contexts, as Marcus recommends.  That's not the type of threading we're talking about.  But you're using GCD (or dispatch_async or `NSThread`), if they're using Core Data too, you can't share the same context between threads.  Each (app) thread needs its own (managed object) context.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79360/discussion-between-jasper-chan-and-petahchristian).